# mask working on simulator but not on Device

Tags: lua, coronasdk

The title of the question takes it away. I have a bunch of masks that are attaches to some images. The masks work the way they are supposed to on the simulator but when I deploy to my tablet my images are gone because they are being covered by the masks. My mask scaling must be off or something but I can't seam to fix it for the life of me.

```
local maskFileArray = {}
maskFileArray[0] = "Images/hydro_screen/hy_screen_river1_mask.png"
maskFileArray[1] = "Images/hydro_screen/hy_screen_river2_mask.png"
maskFileArray[2] = "Images/hydro_screen/hy_screen_river3_mask.png"
maskFileArray[3] = "Images/hydro_screen/hy_screen_river4_mask.png"
maskFileArray[4] = "Images/hydro_screen/hy_screen_river5_mask.png"
maskFileArray[5] = "Images/hydro_screen/hy_screen_river6_mask.png"


local defaultFileArray = {}
  defaultFileArray[0] = "Images/hydro_screen/hy_screen_river1.png"
  defaultFileArray[1] = "Images/hydro_screen/hy_screen_river2.png"  
  defaultFileArray[2] = "Images/hydro_screen/hy_screen_river3.png"
  defaultFileArray[3] = "Images/hydro_screen/hy_screen_river4.png"
  defaultFileArray[4] = "Images/hydro_screen/hy_screen_river5.png"
  defaultFileArray[5] = "Images/hydro_screen/hy_screen_river6.png"



for x = 0, 5, 1 do 

      streams[x] = widget.newButton
      {
          width = display.contentWidth,
          height = display.contentHeight,
          left = 0,
          top = 0,
          defaultFile = defaultFileArray[x],
          onEvent   = function(event) return dam(x + 0,event) end,

      }
      streams[x].anchorY, streams[x].anchorX = 0,0
      streams[x].x = 0
      streams[x].y = 0

      local mask = graphics.newMask( maskFileArray[x] )
      local xScale = streams[x].width/2400
      local yScale = streams[x].height/1600

      streams[x]:setMask( mask )
      streams[x].maskScaleX = xScale
      streams[x].maskScaleY = yScale
      streams[x].maskX = streams[x].width/2
      streams[x].maskY = streams[x].height/2

      sceneGroup:insert(streams[x])
end
```

I use this same algorithm with the masks in other sections in my program and they are showing up fine on the devise. When I say algorithm i mean ike dividing the width and height by 2 and the scaling tactic. I don't know whats wrong with this section.

Something that is different in this section is that my files are much larger then in others. I have attached the first river and mask for you to see. Having them this big allows me to just set the dimensions of the picture to the screen dimensions eliminating positioning problems.

Can anyone help me please??[image: River that should be clickable]

[image: Mask to only make the blue part of the river clickable]

Answer (score 0):

If its working in the simulator but not on the device, general reasons may be,

1. First check the file and folder names, whether its in CAPS or small letters. Generally simulator will not worry about whether its small or CAPS.

This could be the possible problem.

Thanks, KumarKS

Comment: I should have mentioned above that I have checked that with all my files and all the letters are the cases they are supposed to be. Do you have any other ideas?